# Changed singlesite to multisite, but new site shows Maintenance

Tags: multisite

I used these two sites as guidance:
http://www.wpexplorer.com/quick-guide-wordpress-multisite-installation/
https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Original site was example.com
After change to multisite it seems to work.

I added a new site test as test.example.com
The new site shows Maintenance.

If I go to Network Admin - Sites, I see the site test.example.com 
I can Edit it, but I cannot visit the Dashboard nor Visit the site.

What do I miss?

Comment: Have you checked if there's a [`.maintenance`](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/stuck-in-wordpress-maintenance-mode-heres-how-to-get-out-of-it)-file in the root folder?

Comment: no .maintenance file in any directory. I tried to disable all plug-ins, did not change. I used different browser (cleared cache). I used host command a random testxx.example.com, and got my IP. So, wildcard dns seems to be correct too.

Comment: Do you have plugin in the folder `mu-plugins` ? This plugins in this folder work without activation. Which Maintenance you can see, the default maintenance page from WP?

Answer (score 0):

Found it!!!

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf needs this line:
ServerAlias *.example.com
```

(The star was missing! - Merry Xmas)

Comment: Be sure to mark your answer as **accepted** once you're able to (you have to wait 48 hours, IIRC), so that others having a similar problem can find it.